# What is the terminology for creating a UI for an existing CLI Tool

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, webui

I'm having trouble finding a library to help me with a project where I hope to put a WebUI in place to drive an existing CLI Tool. If one doesn't exist I will just produce my own, but I suspect I'm using the wrong terminology. I've tried using 'shell' and 'wrapper' in my searches but those words are often used for other things so I'm coming up dry.

What is the terminology for creating a UI for an existing CLI Tool?

**Original Wording**

I'm looking to write a WebUI to 'wrap?' an existing CLI tool I use. It doesn't seem too difficult to use Child Processes in Node, but got me wondering if there was already a Library that handles alot of the repeatable tasks like mapping the params to a function and parsing the output.

My initial research hasn't brought up anything so I suspect that I may not be aware of the correct terminology for this type of application or behavior?

In the older desktop app days I'd have referred to this a GUI shell/wrapper for a CLI app, but I don't think that is really correct.

Can anyone educate me on the correct terminology and ideally point me towards any NodeJS library that might assist with this. I've no problem with the Web side of things, just really the handling of the CLI executions, keeping track of states and parsing the results.

Comment: ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.***